# Component not updating when array changes

Tags: vue.js, binding

I am new to view, so perhaps this is by design, but just in case.
I have a component that takes a list of **facets** and then splits them up for a nice display.
The code looks like this:

```
import { getFacets } from "@/logic/get-facets";
import {
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
  ref,
  toRefs,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import Filters from "@/components/filters/filters.component.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Chooser",
  components: { Filters },
  emits: ["onFilter"],
  props: {
    categoryName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    facets: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: () => false,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const expanded = ref(false);
    const filters = ref([]);
    const scenarios = ref([]);
    const { facets } = toRefs(props);
    const { criteria } = getFacets(facets.value);

    const expand = () => {
      expanded.value = !expanded.value;
    };

    const addFilter = (attribute: any) => {
      let index = -1;
      for (let i = filters.value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const filter = filters.value[i];
        if (filter.facetName !== attribute.facetName) continue;
        index = i;
        filters.value.splice(i, 1);
      }
      if (index === -1) filters.value.push(attribute);

      instance.proxy.$emit("onFilter", filters.value);
    };

    return { expanded, criteria, filters, scenarios, expand, addFilter };
  },
});
```

The `getFacets` method looks like this:

```
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

class Facet {
  key: string;
  value: FacetItem[];
}

class FacetItem {
  facetName: string;
  count: number;
  value: string;
  from: string;
  to: string;
}

export function getFacets(facets: any) {
  const criteria = ref([]);

  const facet = facets.find((item: Facet) => item.key === "Criteria/Attribute");

  let currentCriterionName = "";
  let criterion: any = {};
  let count = 0;
  (<Facet>facet).value
    .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value))
    .forEach((item: FacetItem) => {
      const value = item.value;
      const [c, a] = value.split(":");

      if (c !== currentCriterionName) {
        if (criterion.name) criteria.value.push(criterion);

        criterion = {
          name: c,
          attributes: [],
          active: false,
        };

        currentCriterionName = c;
      }

      criterion.attributes.push({
        name: a,
        facetName: value,
        to: item.to,
        from: item.from,
        count: item.count,
      });
      count++;
    });

  if (count === facet.value.length) criteria.value.push(criterion);

  return { criteria };
}
```

As you can see, my component expects a **facets** array that is required (along with a categoryName and optional loading boolean).
The initial array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key":"Criteria/Attribute",
    "value":[
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Capacity:Extra Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":11,
          "value":"Capacity:Large",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":13,
          "value":"Capacity:Medium",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":19,
          "value":"Capacity:Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":8,
          "value":"Coffee at the press of a button?:Yes",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":13,
          "value":"Extraction Quality:Amazing",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Extraction Quality:Exceptional",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":24,
          "value":"Extraction Quality:Good",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":6,
          "value":"Extraction Quality:Very Good",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":16,
          "value":"Milk Frother:Automatic",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":10,
          "value":"Milk Frother:None",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":22,
          "value":"Milk Frother:Steam Wand",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":10,
          "value":"Noise:Buzzing",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":10,
          "value":"Noise:Loud",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":23,
          "value":"Noise:Quiet",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Noise:Silent",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":3,
          "value":"Size:Extra Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":6,
          "value":"Size:Large",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":31,
          "value":"Size:Medium",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":8,
          "value":"Size:Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":2,
          "value":"Speed:Instant",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":28,
          "value":"Speed:Quick Heat",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Speed:Slow",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":13,
          "value":"Speed:Standard",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":7,
          "value":"Style:Designer",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":8,
          "value":"Style:Minimalist",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":20,
          "value":"Style:Modern",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":13,
          "value":"Style:Professional",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        }
    ],
    "__typename":"KeyValuePairOfStringAndListOfFacetModel"
  }
]
```

In this component, when one of the items is clicked, it performs a search which returns a new set of facets. Here is an example of the new array:

```
[
  {
    "key":"Criteria/Attribute",
    "value":[
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Capacity:Extra Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Extraction Quality:Good",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Milk Frother:None",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Noise:Silent",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Speed:Slow",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":5,
          "value":"Style:Minimalist",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":3,
          "value":"Size:Extra Small",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        },
        {
          "count":2,
          "value":"Size:Medium",
          "from":null,
          "to":null,
          "__typename":"FacetModel"
        }
    ],
    "__typename":"KeyValuePairOfStringAndListOfFacetModel"
  }
]
```

This is all served from a parent component. The initial array is produced when the page loads, when the filter is clicked above, it then calls a method that updates the array which the **Chooser** component uses.

```
<chooser
  :categoryName="category.name"
  :facets="result.search.facets"
  :loading="loading"
  @onFilter="search($event)"
>
</chooser>
```

The problem is, even though I can do this `{{ result.search.facets }}` in the parent component and see the array change, the **Chooser** remains exactly the same.
Is there something I must do in order for the **Chooser** to update when the array changes?

Comment: Are you mutating `result.search.facets` array or completely replacing it?

Comment: `criteria` should be [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) so it is rebuild (by executing `getFacets` function) each time the `fasets` prop changes.

Comment: completely replacing it

Answer (score 1):

Try not only to update an array but also to update a link of `filters` variable. I think that the problem is that Vue does not always detect changes on elements of array. Here is what is written in [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) about it.